# how to make Time series line Plot in R using Year and months and group by town

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to visualise the following dataset in a line plot based on years and months. It shows the discharge for each month in each year. Therefore I want to show the line graph with discharge from 1997 January to December until the last year 2019 December.

```
structure(list(Year = c(1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997), Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               Discharge = c(338.480838709677, 293.052964285714, 232.63664516129, 
                             631.0761, 352.923612903226), Town = c("Vioolsdrif",  
                       "Vioolsdrif", "Vioolsdrif", "Vioolsdrif", "Vioolsdrif")),
          row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: your dput() outcome is not reproducible

Comment: I edited it, can you try it now.

Comment: still looking the same

Comment: let me make it small. Maybe 10 rows is too much.

Comment: before update the question, you had better try on your local computer to reproduce your data from the code you post. still not workin

Comment: It is skipping the first lines of the code, I am not sure why it does that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231570/discussion-between-ndahambelela-and-samet-sokel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a date object and then plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, 1, sep = '-'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Discharge)) + geom_line()
```

Use `scale_x_date` to include breaks and label x-axis dates if needed.

Comment: Sure, How do I group the lines based on the column 'Town'?

Comment: Do you want to include `group = Town` and `color = Town` in `aes` ?

Comment: I tried `group = Town` but nothing changed in the plot. I will try the `colour = Town`

Comment: It is difficult to help with data of only one `Town`. Can you include data of at-least two towns to help you in a better way?